# How to do a partial deep-merge based on changed property value of inner array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm trying to do update an array of object values based on another array of associated changed values.  The initial array:

```
const primaryArray = [
  { 
  name: 'Product Family 1',
  products: [ {name: 'product 1', selected: false}, {name: 'product 2', selected: false}
  ]},
  { 
  name: 'Product Family 2',
  products: [ {name: 'product 3', selected: false}, {name: 'product 4', selected: false}
  ]},
];
```

the array of updated items:

```
const updates = [
  { 
  name: 'Product Family 1',
  products: [ {name: 'product 2', selected: true}]
  },
  { 
  name: 'Product Family 2',
  products: [ {name: 'product 4', selected: true}]
  },
];
```

Essentially only the products listed in the updates array should be changed in the primary array, whilst still retaining the existing unchanged products

I've tried multiple variations on Object.assign and _.mergeWith none of which is working as intending due to the varying number of elements in the primaryArray vs the 'updates' array e.g:

```
    const newArray = primaryArray.forEach(obj => {
      return (updates.find(o => o.name === obj.name) || obj);
    });
```

I've also attempted multiple variations of using .map in combination .find and .forEach without any luck.

The expected result should be:

```
const newArray = [
  { 
  name: 'Product Family 1',
  products: [ {name: 'product 1', selected: false}, {name: 'product 2', selected: true}
  ]},
  { 
  name: 'Product Family 2',
  products: [ {name: 'product 3', selected: false}, {name: 'product 4', selected: true}
  ]},
  ....
  // where the new Array will also inherit all other objects from the primaryArray
  name: 'Product Family 102',
  products: [ {name: 'product 1000', selected: false}
  ]},
];
```

Comment: Note: the format of the 'updates' array is not set in stone, and its 'products' property could instead be changed to an array of strings (product names) instead if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd turn `updates` into a hashtable first:

```
 const updateByName = {};

 for(const { name, products } of updates)
   for(const {name: inner, selected } of products)
       updateByName[name + " > " + inner] = selected;
```

The  updating is as easy as:

```
 const result = primaryArray.map(({ name, products }) => ({
   name,
   products: products.map(({ name: inner, selected }) => {
      const update = updateByName[name + " > " + inner];
      return {
        name: inner,
        selected: update !== undefined ? update : selected,
      };
   })),
 }));
```

This will be slightly more elegant with the [null coalescing operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing/blob/master/README.md) which will be available soon.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks Jonas!  Still a bit fuzzy on the how and why of using a hashtable but that's working perfectly.